# Parallelize curl requests

Tags: shell-scripting

This is my shell script:

```
for i in `seq 1 $1`; do
    filename=randomfile$(uuidgen).txt
    head -c $2 </dev/urandom > $filename
    checksum256=$(sha256sum $filename | awk '{ print $1 }')
    attrs=$(jq -n --arg cf "$checksum256" '{ "confidential":"N", "transactionId": "sdf", "codiDirCorp": "CorpCode", "expiration": "10/10/2025", "description": "desc", "locked": "N", "title": "titol", "docHash": $cf }')

    curl -X POST \
        'http://localhost:8083/documents?application=RDOCUI&user=nif' \
        -F docFile=@$filename \
        -F 'docAttributes='"${attrs}"''
done
```

As you can see, I'm generating several files with randomized content.

After that, I just perform a curl request in order to upload them.

In order to perform that command, I just type:

```
$ ./stress.sh 1000 200K
```

Here, I generate 1000 files and 1000 request uploadting them.

I would like to speed it up running those request in parallel.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try an amperands (&) behind the curl command?

Comment: hows about xargs?

Comment: You could always call multiple instances of your script at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xargs can do that in foreground and it gives you control over parallelism and batching. Curl will reuse an open connection to send all requests in a batch.

`-P 42` defines how many `curl`s to run at a time.
`-n 23` defines how many requests each `curl` invocation will handle.
`-n 1` disables batching.

## With Bash

```
#! /bin/bash

URL='http://localhost:8083/documents?application=RDOCUI&user=nif'

for i in `seq $1`
do
    filename=randomfile$(uuidgen).txt
    head -c $2 </dev/urandom > $filename
    export checksum256=$(sha256sum $filename | awk '{ print $1 }')
    attrs=$(jq -n '{ "foo": "bar", "docHash": env.checksum256 }')

    printf -- '--next %q -F docFile=@%q -F docAttributes=%q\0' "$URL" "$filename" "$attrs"
done |
    xargs -0 -n 23 -P 42 bash -c 'eval "$0" "$@"' curl
```

The `for` loop writes `\0`-separated groups of space separated arguments to the pipe for Xargs to read.
Those arguments want to be passed to Curl.
Xargs in turn passes them to Bash, so they get assigned to `"$1"`, `"$2"`, ... (a.k.a. `"$@"`).
Now we use `eval` to ungroup the arguments.
Any special characters have been properly escaped using `printf %q`, so Bash won't do any unwanted quote removal or word splitting.
`"$0" "$@"` will expand to `curl --next http://l... --next ...`

Curl will try to make just one TCP handshake and reuse that persistent connection for sending all the requests listed in its arguments. Depending on the request size that may give some noticeable speed-up.

## With Dash

Dash doesn't support `printf %q`, but if your JSON formatting can be sacrified (via `jq -c`)
you can escape it with `printf '%s'`. We'll also have to rely on the assumption that neither JSON nor other arguments contain `'`.

```
#! /bin/sh

# ...

    attrs=$(jq -n -c '{ "foo": "bar", "docHash": env.checksum256 }')

    printf -- "--next %s -F 'docFile=@%s' -F 'docAttributes=%s'\0" "$URL" "$filename" "$attrs"
done |
    xargs -0 -n 23 -P 42 sh -c 'eval "$0" "$@"' curl
```

## Without `for`

You asked specifically about running in parallel the request part. But if you'd like to
run in parallel the whole script, you can type the command in the following fashion

```
$ seq 1000 | xargs -n 1 -P 42 ./stress.sh 1 200K
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always have a look at [nohup](https://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html)

```
for i in `seq 1 $1`; do
    filename=randomfile$(uuidgen).txt
    head -c $2 </dev/urandom > $filename
    checksum256=$(sha256sum $filename | awk '{ print $1 }')
    attrs=$(jq -n --arg cf "$checksum256" '{ "confidential":"N", "transactionId": "sdf", "codiDirCorp": "CorpCode", "expiration": "10/10/2025", "description": "desc", "locked": "N", "title": "titol", "docHash": $cf }')

    nohup curl -X POST \
        'http://localhost:8083/documents?application=RDOCUI&user=nif' \
        -F docFile=@$filename \
        -F 'docAttributes='"${attrs}"''
done
```

nohup tells the shell to run the process in the background without user input, ignoring hangup signals. So you should have multiple CURL's running at the same time

Comment: There are different implementations of nohup, but I have never come across one which runs processes in the background. Even if it did, there are easier ways of running a parallele process.